# Scala recover or recoverWith

Tags: scala, error-handling, future

We are developing some systems in our company in Scala and we have some doubts. We were discussing about how to map the future exceptions and we don't know when we should use the option 1 or the option 2.

```
val created: Future[...] = ???
```

Option 1:

```
val a = created recover {   
  case e: database.ADBException =>
    logger.error("Failed ...", e)
    throw new business.ABusinessException("Failed ...", e) 
}
```

Option 2:

```
val a = created recoverWith {   
  case e: database.ADBException =>
    logger.error("Failed ...", e)
    Future.failed(new business.ABusinessException("Failed ...", e))
}
```

Could someone explain when should i do the option 1 or the option 2? What is the diff?

Comment: To be somewhat pedantic 3 years later for others who find this question, generally speaking the point of "recover" and "recoverWith" is not to simply transform your exceptions from one type to another, but to *recover* from the failure by performing the task in a different way so that you no longer have a failure. In that case, your use of "recover" vs "recoverWith" is dependent on whether the *new* recovery task happens inside a Future or without a Future.

Comment: @Azuaron So if you simply need to transform exceptions, what do you recommend to use instead of `recover`? https://stackoverflow.com/q/59099000/14955

Comment: `recover` is still pretty much the only option, unfortunately, but it's important to understand what you're taking advantage of.

Comment: @Thilo there is `transform` to transform the exception.

Answer (score 90, accepted):

Well, the answer is clearly described in scaladocs:

```
  /** Creates a new future that will handle any matching throwable that this
   *  future might contain. If there is no match, or if this future contains
   *  a valid result then the new future will contain the same.
   *
   *  Example:
   *
   *  {{{
   *  Future (6 / 0) recover { case e: ArithmeticException => 0 } // result: 0
   *  Future (6 / 0) recover { case e: NotFoundException   => 0 } // result: exception
   *  Future (6 / 2) recover { case e: ArithmeticException => 0 } // result: 3
   *  }}}
   */
  def recover[U >: T](pf: PartialFunction[Throwable, U])(implicit executor: ExecutionContext): Future[U] = {

  /** Creates a new future that will handle any matching throwable that this
   *  future might contain by assigning it a value of another future.
   *
   *  If there is no match, or if this future contains
   *  a valid result then the new future will contain the same result.
   *
   *  Example:
   *
   *  {{{
   *  val f = Future { Int.MaxValue }
   *  Future (6 / 0) recoverWith { case e: ArithmeticException => f } // result: Int.MaxValue
   *  }}}
   */
  def recoverWith[U >: T](pf: PartialFunction[Throwable, Future[U]])(implicit executor: ExecutionContext): Future[U] = {
```

`recover` wraps plain result in `Future` for you (analogue of `map`), while `recoverWith` expects `Future` as the result (analogue of `flatMap`).

So, here is rule of thumb:

If you recover with something that already returns `Future`, use `recoverWith`, otherwise use `recover`.

**update**
In your case, using `recover` is preferred, as it wraps the exception in `Future` for you. Otherwise there is no performance gain or anything, so you just avoid some boilerplate.

Answer (score 26):

Using `recoverWith` you are asked to return a wrapped future, using `recover` you are asked to throw an exception.

```
.recoverWith # => Future.failed(t)
.recover # => throw t
```

I prefer using `recoverWith` because I think functional programming prefers returning objects than throwing exceptions which is less of a functional style, even if it's internal code block, I think it still holds..

However if I have an internal piece of code in the recovery block which might throw an exception then, in that case, rather than catching it and wrapping it with `Future`, or Trying it, I might as well just run this piece of code in combination with `recover` and it would handle the exception wrapping for you, which would make the code more readable and compact.