# How to NOT throw an exception?

Tags: scala, slick, slick-3.0

I have the following Slick code that given an id returns a customer (if exists). If there's a problem (such as connectivity lost) a `Failure` clause will throw an exception:

```
   def read (id: Int): Future[Option[Customer]] = {
      val db = // .... 
      val customers = TableQuery[CustomerDB]
      val action = customers.filter(_.id === id).result
      val future = db.run(action.asTry)
      future.map{
        case Success(s) => 
          if (s.length>0)
            Some(s(0))
          else
            None
        case Failure(f) => throw new Exception (f.getMessage)
      }
   }
```

Now, my understanding is that instead of using try/catch/finally of exceptions, in Scala one should use Try. In addition, no exceptions should be thrown. But if the exception is not thrown, how to notify the upper layer that a problem occurred?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The right way to do report errors is by using Either.

```
trait Error
case class NotFound(id: Int) extends Error
case class QueryFailed(msg: String) extends Error

def read (id: Int): Future[Either[Error, Customer]] = {
   val db = // .... 
   val customers = TableQuery[CustomerDB]
   val action = customers.filter(_.id === id).result
   val future = db.run(action.asTry)
   future.map{
      case Success(s) => 
         if (s.length>0)
           Right(s(0))
         else
           Left(NotFound(id))

      case Failure(f) => Left(QueryFailed(f.getMessage))
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Knows Not Much!

Answer (score 3):

`Future` itself does already have Try inside. So, I would say that you need to just flatten (also you code a bit complicated, I simplified):

```
  future.flatMap {
    case Success(s) => Future.successful(s.headOption)
    case Failure(f) => Future.failed(f)
  }
```

Result `Future` when in `failed` state notifies caller that execution failed (with wrapped original exception). Otherwise, successful.

Comment: why do you flatten it?

Comment: What the reason to throw new exception if you already have one with real cause? By wrapping message with new Exception you just hide this cause. Your goal is to pass failure of DBIO operation to caller, what could be archived by converting successful `Future` with `Failure` inside into failed `Future` with real cause of failure

Comment: Your solution works, but I like the fact that in Either I can return classes

Answer (score 0):

Ok so, in general you can use Future.successful or Future.failed(msg: String) to "signal" the upper level (aka calling method) you got the value or not.

Better approach

A good approach is however to use `.recoverWith{}` on a Future in case of failure.

For example:

```
def getUserFromCloud (userId: String): Future[String] = Future{
  cloudProviderApi.getUsername(userId)
}.recoverWith{
  Future.failed(s"$userId does not exist.")    
}
```

What about the calling method?

Well you just map the success with and underscode and deal with the error by using recover:

```
getUserFromCloud("test").map(_ => {
    //In case of success
}).recover{
    //In case of failure, like return BadRequest. 
}
```

More on `recover` and `recoverWith` in case you are interested: [Scala recover or recoverWith](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36584845/scala-recover-or-recoverwith)