# How to transform failed future exceptions in Scala?

Tags: scala, exception, future

I have always used `recover` to transform exceptions in failed futures similar to

```scala
def selectFromDatabase(id: Long): Future[Entity] = ???

val entity = selectFromDatabase(id) recover {   
  case e: DatabaseException =>
    logger.error("Failed ...", e)
    throw new BusinessException("Failed ...", e) 
}
```

This code snippet transforms a `DatabaseException` into a `BusinessException`. However, from a comment in the question: [Scala recover or recoverWith](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36584845/scala-recover-or-recoverwith)

> ... generally speaking the point of "recover" and "recoverWith" is not to simply transform your exceptions from one type to another, but to recover from the failure by performing the task in a different way so that you no longer have a failure.

So apparently I am not supposed to use `recover` to transform exceptions. What is the correct way to transform `Future` exceptions / failed `Future`?

Comment: If you need to transform a Failure to another Failure, `recover` (or slightly better `recoverWith { .... Future.failed(new BusinessException` to avoid the `throw`) is fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you are simply transforming an exception to another exception, I think using `recover` is ok. Use `recoverWith` when you want to try a different strategy for solving the problem, that is, when you hope to get a successful result back. For example consider the following use of `recoverWith`

```
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
import scala.concurrent.Future

object futureRecoverWith extends App {

  case class Entity(id: Int, name: String)

  def selectFromDatabaseById(id: Int): Future[Entity] = Future(throw new RuntimeException("Boom"))
  def selectFromDatabaseByName(name: String): Future[Entity] = Future(Entity(42, "picard"))

  val entity =
    selectFromDatabaseById(42) recoverWith {
      case error =>
        println("Failed to get Entity by ID. Trying by name...")
        selectFromDatabaseByName("picard")
    }

  entity.map(println)
}
```

which outputs

```
Failed to get Entity by ID. Trying by name...
Entity(42,picard)
```

Note how we attempted to first get the entity by `id`, and then failing that, we attempted by `name`.

Comment: What about using `transform` to avoid _throwing_ the exception but rather returning a new **Failed** _(the downside is doing an identity on the **Success**)_.